# Chunksize irrelevant for multiprocessing / pool.map in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I try to utilize the pool multiprocessing functionality of python.

Independent how I set the chunk size (under Windows 7 and Ubuntu - the latter see below with 4 cores), the amount of parallel threads seems to stay the same.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import multiprocessing
import time


def f(x):
    print("ready to sleep", x, multiprocessing.current_process())
    time.sleep(20)
    print("slept with:", x, multiprocessing.current_process())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = cpu_count()
    print('-' * 20)
    print('Utilizing %d cores' % processes)
    print('-' * 20)
    pool = Pool(processes)
    myList = []
    runner = 0
    while runner < 40:
        myList.append(runner)
        runner += 1
    print("len(myList):", len(myList))

    # chunksize = int(len(myList) / processes)
    # chunksize = processes
    chunksize = 1
    print("chunksize:", chunksize)
    pool.map(f, myList, 1)
```

The behaviour is the same whether I use `chunksize = int(len(myList) / processes)`, `chunksize = processes` or `1` (as in the example above).

Could it be that the chunksize is set automatically to the amount of cores?

Example for `chunksize = 1`:

```
--------------------
Utilizing 4 cores
--------------------
len(myList): 40
chunksize: 10
ready to sleep 0 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
ready to sleep 1 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
ready to sleep 2 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
ready to sleep 3 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-4, started daemon)>
slept with: 0 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
ready to sleep 4 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
slept with: 1 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
ready to sleep 5 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
slept with: 2 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
ready to sleep 6 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
slept with: 3 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-4, started daemon)>
ready to sleep 7 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-4, started daemon)>
slept with: 4 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
ready to sleep 8 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
slept with: 5 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
ready to sleep 9 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
slept with: 6 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
ready to sleep 10 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
slept with: 7 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-4, started daemon)>
ready to sleep 11 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-4, started daemon)>
slept with: 8 <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
```

Comment: I'm confused; why would chunksize set the number of cores when that's configurable, in a loose way, with pool size?

Comment: Maybe this is also the reason for my question. At least the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.__init__) states: `This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.`

Comment: That's saying how large the data chunks are that are sent to each process. I have a pizza and 4 guests. Do I chop the pizza into quarters and give each guest one big slice, or do I chop it into 16 pieces and let each guest eat 4? Neither decision changes the number of guests at the table, but it does change the frequency at which they need to grab new slices.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Chunksize doesn't influence how many cores are getting used, this is set by the `processes` parameter of `Pool`. Chunksize sets how many items of the iterable you pass to `Pool.map`, are distributed per single worker-process **at once** in what `Pool` calls a "task" (figure below shows Python 3.7.1).

[image: task_python_3.7.1]

In case you set `chunksize=1`, a worker-process gets fed with a new item, in a new task, only after finishing the one received before. For `chunksize > 1` a worker gets a whole batch of items at once within a task and when it's finished, it gets the next batch if there are any left.

Distributing items one-by-one with `chunksize=1` increases flexibility of scheduling while it decreases overall throughput, because drip feeding requires more inter-process communication (IPC).

In my in-depth analysis of Pool's chunksize-algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54032744/9059420), I define the **unit of work** for processing *one* item of the iterable as **taskel**, to avoid naming conflicts with Pool's usage of the word "task". A task (as unit of work) consists of `chunksize` taskels.

You would set `chunksize=1` if you cannot predict how long a taskel will need to finish, for example an optimization problem, where the processing time greatly varies across taskels. Drip-feeding here prevents a worker-process sitting on a pile of untouched items, while chrunching on one heavy taskel, preventing the other items in his task to be distributed to idling worker-processes.

Otherwise, if all your taskels will need the same time to finish, you can set `chunksize=len(iterable) // processes`, so that tasks are only distributed once across all workers. Note that this will produce one more task than there are processes (processes + 1) in case `len(iterable) / processes` has a remainder. This has the potential to severely impact your overall computation time. Read more about this in the previously linked answer.

---

FYI, that's the part of source code where `Pool` internally calculates the chunksize if not set:

```
    # Python 3.6, line 378 in `multiprocessing.pool.py`
    if chunksize is None:
        chunksize, extra = divmod(len(iterable), len(self._pool) * 4)
        if extra:
            chunksize += 1
    if len(iterable) == 0:
        chunksize = 0
```

Comment: I was with you until the last paragraph. Is there any _need_ to set this at all? Can you realistically get something better than the default performance in a general case? I'm not sure you'd be able to guess better unless you're in one of the exceptional cases you detail

Comment: @roganjosh In my experience yes, fiddling with this parameter makes sense. If all your tasks need the same time you are just waisting time by letting the workers wait for new tasks if it makes sense to distribute all at once.

Comment: Actually, yeah, that makes sense. I had in my head it was default behaviour when not specified. Thanks.

Comment: @roganjosh Good hint, I added the relevant source snippet.