# Reading large file with Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, large-files

I am trying to read a large text file  > 20Gb  with python. 
File contains positions of atoms for 400 frames and each frame is independent in terms of my computations in this code. In theory I can split the job to 400 tasks without any need of communication. Each frame has 1000000 lines so the file has 1000 000* 400 lines of text.
My initial approach is using multiprocessing with pool of workers:

```
def main():
   """ main function
   """
   filename=sys.argv[1]
   nump = int(sys.argv[2])
   f = open(filename)
   s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
   cursor = 0
   framelocs=[]
   start = time.time()
   print (mp.cpu_count())
   chunks = []
   while True:
        initial = s.find(b'ITEM: TIMESTEP', cursor)
        if initial == -1:
            break
        cursor = initial + 14
        final = s.find(b'ITEM: TIMESTEP', cursor)
        framelocs.append([initial,final])
        #readchunk(s[initial:final])
        chunks.append(s[initial:final])
        if final == -1:
           break
```

Here basically I am seeking file to find frame begins and ends with opening file with python mmap module to avoid reading everything into memory.

```
def readchunk(chunk):
   start = time.time()
   part = chunk.split(b'\n')
   timestep= int(part[1])
   print(timestep)
```

Now I would like to send chunks of file to pool of workers to process.
Read part should be more complex but those lines will be implemented later.

```
   print('Seeking file took %8.6f'%(time.time()-start))
   pool = mp.Pool(nump)
   start = time.time()
   results= pool.map(readchunk,chunks[0:16])
   print('Reading file took %8.6f'%(time.time()-start))
```

If I run this with sending 8 chunks to 8 cores it would take 0.8 sc to read.
However 
If I run this with sending 16 chunks to 16 cores it would take 1.7 sc. Seems like parallelization does not speed up. I am running this on Oak Ridge's Summit supercomputer if it is relevant, I am using this command:

```
jsrun -n1 -c16 -a1 python -u ~/Developer/DipoleAnalyzer/AtomMan/readlargefile.py DW_SET6_NVT.lammpstrj 16
```

This supposed to create 1 MPI task and assign 16 cores to 16 threads.
Am I missing here something?
Is there a better approach?

Comment: (1) I'm not sure if this really avoids copying of the chunks. Better send only the chunk boundaries to subprocesses and let them read the actual chunk. (2) A simple test code may have more overhead than actual work so the times may not be representative.

Comment: Parallelization isn't going to speed up disk I/O to the single physical drive containing the file — and using multiprocess often introduces a fair amount of overhead on it's own.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, there is some overhead when making processes so you could see a slowdown if testing with small samples.

Something like this might be neater.  Make sure you understand what the generator function is doing.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
import mmap


def do_something_with_frame(frame):
    print("processing a frame:")
    return 100


def frame_supplier(filename):
    """A generator for frames"""
    f = open(filename)
    s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

    cursor = 0
    while True:
        initial = s.find(b'ITEM: TIMESTEP', cursor)
        if initial == -1:
            break
        cursor = initial + 14
        final = s.find(b'ITEM: TIMESTEP', cursor)

        yield s[initial:final]

        if final == -1:
            break


def main():
    """Process a file of atom frames

    Args:
      filename: the file to process
      processes: the size of the pool
    """
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    nump = int(sys.argv[2])

    frames = frame_supplier(filename)

    pool = mp.Pool(nump)

    # play around with the chunksize
    for result in pool.imap(do_something_with_frame, frames, chunksize=10):
        print(result)
```

Disclaimer: this is a suggestion.  There may be some syntax errors.  I haven't tested it.

EDIT:

- It sounds like your script is becoming I/O limited (i.e. limited by the rate at which you can read from disk). You should be able to verify this by setting the body of `do_something_with_frame` to `pass`.  If the program is I/O bound, it will still take nearly as long.
- I don't think MPI is going to make any difference here. I think that file-read speed is probably a limiting factor and I don't see how MPI will help.
- It's worth doing some profiling at this point to find out which function calls are taking the longest.
- It is also worth trying without mmap():

```or-tag-here
frame = []
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.beginswith('ITEM: TIMESTEP'):
            yield frame
        else:
            frame.append(line)
```

Comment: Can you explain little bit?
Here chunksize=10 means you are sending 10 frames to each pool worker?
Also results here are ordered?

Comment: I have tested your code and it is much more neat then mine. However when I run this on 8 cores or 16 cores it still gives the same speed about 103 seconds to read the file which is 20gb. Is there a race condition accessing the same file between pool workers?
Do you think MPI4PY would be better approach?

Comment: @dundar yilmaz, yes, chunksize=10 means you are sending 10 frames to each pool worker.  I'm not sure what implications this has for memory usage.  The answer to this question gives, IMO, a good explanation:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306927/chunksize-irrelevant-for-multiprocessing-pool-map-in-python/53307813