# Python multiprocessing: chunksize parameter not respected, always sends 1 item

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

After reading @Darkonaut 's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53307813/534347) I am still having trouble getting ***batches*** of my iterable sent to the function to be multiprocessed.

My set up:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.7 :: Anaconda, Inc.
OS X 10.15.7
Also tested on RHEL 8, same result.
```

Here is a minimal example with the output below

```
import multiprocessing
from itertools import repeat

iterable = list(range(1000))

def dummy_func(arg1, arg2):
    if hasattr( arg1, "__len__"):
        print(f"Batch size: {len(arg1)}")
    else:
        print("Single item sent to func.")

    print(f"Arg1: {arg1}, Arg2: {arg2}")

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
    pool.starmap(
        dummy_func, 
        zip(
            iterable, 
            repeat("Static second variable")),
        chunksize = 10)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

No matter if chunksize is None, or any number above 1, it aways sends a single item.
Output:

```
Single item sent to func.
Arg1: 0, Arg2: Static second variable
Single item sent to func.
Arg1: 1, Arg2: Static second variable
Single item sent to func.
Arg1: 2, Arg2: Static second variable
...
Arg1: 989, Arg2: Static second variable
```

My expectation was that arg1 would be a list of items of length chunksize, is that not correct?

Comment: No, that's not right. `chunksize` determines how many individual pieces of work a worker does before it returns to the iterable to collect more items. That is, if `chunksize=10`, then a worker will take ten items from the iterable, process them each individually, return the ten values back to main, and ask for ten more values, etc. C.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751050/python-multiprocessing-understanding-logic-behind-chunksize

Comment: @BallpointBen Ok, so internally the process/worker IS taking chunksize items, but my function will ever only process one at a time. That is reassuring, but not well conveyed in the documentation. Do you want to make your comment an answer so i can give you credit?